# python pyramid pattern print using for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration

how do you manipulate the for loop to display an output just like

```
5
54
543
5432
54321
```

I tried coding like

```
n=6
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range (n,0):
        print(j,end="")
print(i)
```

but it would print this

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Shouldn't it print first the 5 in loop j first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bunch of ways to solve this... here's one:

```
n = 5

for i in range(0, n):
    # Think of this range as "how many numbers to print on this line"
    for j in range(i + 1):
        # First number should be n, second n - 1, etc.
        print(n - j, end="")
    print() # newline before next i
```

(Note that I changed n to 5.)

Comment: I noticed you didn't put a second number in the j range. Why is it possible?

Comment: @CzarLuc Because the default value for the first argument is a zero.

Answer (score 3):

Almost good, but to go down from `n`, `range` requires the third parameter - step - to be `-1`:

```
for i in range(n,0,-1):
    for j in range (n,i-1,-1):
        print(j,end="")
    print()
```

Comment: so i should replace the range in j to be (n,-1)?

Comment: i just tried it and its good.Can you explain it how it works? I'm kind off confused on how it performs the code.